# How to sort array in a method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

Hello people!

The compiling of my program is done successfully...

The problem is on method total4... As im coding in eclipse while I'm running the program it appears a problem on line with the "IF" in method called total4!!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Askisi1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ch=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] onomata= new String[6];
        int[] pontoi1=new int[10];
        int[] pontoi2=new int[10];
        int[][] pontoi=new int [6][10];
        double[] taxinomisi=new double[6];

        int i,k;


            for (i=0; i<onomata.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Parakalw doste to onoma tou"+" " +(i+1)+"ou"+" "+"paixti!");
                onomata[i] =  ch.nextLine();

            }

            for (i=0; i<=5; i++)
            {
                for (k=0; k<=9; k++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Parakalw doste tous pontous tou"+" " +(i+1)+"ou"+" "+"paixti ston"+" " +(k+1)+"o"+" "+"agwna!!");
                    pontoi[i][k]=in.nextInt();
                }
            }

            pontoi1=total1(pontoi);
            pontoi2=total2(pontoi);
            taxinomisi=total3(pontoi1);

            for (i=0; i<=5; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Oi pontoi tou"+" "+(i+1)+"ou paixti einai"+" "+pontoi1[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
            for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Oi pontoi tis omadas ston"+" "+(i+1)+"o agwna einai:"+" "+pontoi2[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ");

            for (i=0; i<=5; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(" "+total4(taxinomisi,onomata)+" ");
                System.out.println(onomata[i]);
            }


    }

        public static int[] total1 (int[][] array) {


                    int total=0;
                    int z=0; int j=0;
                    int[] a=new int[6];
                    for (z=0; z<=5; z++)
                    {
                        for (j=0; j<=9; j++)
                        {
                            total=total+array[z][j];
                        }
                        a[z]=total;
                        total=0;
                    }

                    return a;
                }

        public static int[] total2 (int[][] array) {
                    int total2 = 0; 
                    int z=0; int j=0; 
                    int[] b=new int[10];

                    do{

                    for (z=0; z<=5; z++)
                    {
                        total2=total2+array[z][j];

                    }
                    b[j]=total2;
                    total2=0;
                    j++;
                    }
                    while (j<=9);

                    return b;
                    }

        public static double[] total3 (int[] array){
            double mesos_oros=0.0;
            int z=0;
            double[] a=new double[6];
            for (z=0; z<=5; z++)
            {
                mesos_oros=array[z]/10;
                a[z]=mesos_oros;
                mesos_oros=0.0;
            }
            return a;

        }

        public static double[] total4 (double[] array,String[] array2){
            String y=" ";
            double x=0.0;
            double max=array[0];
            for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
            {
                if (array[i+1]>max)
                {
                    array[i]=x;
                    array[i+1]=array[i];
                    array[i+1]=x;
                    array2[i]=y;
                    array2[i+1]=array2[i];
                    array2[i+1]=y;

                }
            }

            return array;
        }

}
```

I'm just trying to sort the array, but I cant see any mistake...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the problem in detail?

Comment: Telling us what exception is being thrown, or what kind of unexpected behavior is happening would help us help you.

Comment: `if (array[i+1]>max)` is very suspicious, Java uses zero based array indexing.

Comment: You need to read the Help Center on how to ask a question. You've told us what you want to happen, but you haven't told us what actually happens.

Comment: What happens actually? When the compiler get in method called total4, when it arrives on line with the "IF", it just stops the programm without doing anything else... I guess, it just can't compare what i ask for while i cant find out why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `if (array[i + 1] > max)`, and more specifically with `array[i+1]`.

You call `total4` on this line:

```
System.out.print(" " + total4(taxinomisi, onomata) + " ");
```

So the `array` passed in is `taxinomisi`.

You set `taxinomisi` here: `taxinomisi = total3(pontoi1);`

In `total3` you return:

```
double[] a = new double[6];
// stuff
return a;
```

So you're passing `taxinomisi`, an array of length 6, into `total4`. Now let's look at the loop in `total4`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (array[i + 1] > max)
```

We can see here that when `i` is 5, `array[i+1]` will look for element 6 in the array. However, arrays in Java are zero-based: They start at 0. So you're actually looking for the 7th element in the array (if we start from 1). However, the array only has 6 elements, casuing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

In fact, the error message tells you this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at stuff.Stuff.total4(Stuff.java:106)
    at stuff.Stuff.main(Stuff.java:45)

Java Result: 1
```